# Selecting current/actual/initialfocused date with CalendarView

Tags: android, android-layout, calendarview

I've seen some similar questions, with no specific answer.. Has anyone done it?  The problem is with the use of :

```
CalendarView calendarView=(CalendarView) findViewById(R.id.calendarView1); 
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new OnDateChangeListener() { 

        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView view, int year, int month,
                int dayOfMonth) {     .........................ETC.......
```

When the CalendarView is first displayed, with the current(e.g. today's date) date on focus, if you click that date, there's no response, because there's no change in date...  If you click any other date it works perfectly..  Please help, I'm stuck.  Thanks.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, you can check out my answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25231041/923920