# calendar view onclick listener for todays date does not work

Tags: android, datepicker, onclicklistener, calendarview

How to set a onclick listener for a calendar view for "TODAYS DATE" ? the code is working for onclick yesterdays date or tomorrows date, but it does not work for todays date ? can somebody help on this please ?

Code:

**MainActivity.java**:

```
final CalendarView calendarview=(CalendarView)findViewById(R.id.Calendarview);
final Button selectDate=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Date_seletcion_btn);

selectDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

calendarview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


}
});

calendarview.setClickable(true);

//calendarview.getSelectedDateVerticalBar();
/*calendarview.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView calendarview, int year, int month,
int day) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
int day1, month1, year1;

day1=day;
month1=month;
year1=year;


Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();


clickeddate=calendarview.getDate();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(clickeddate);

//ArrayList<> array=calendar.getTouchables();

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Date Selected: " + day,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


Intent homein=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),HomePageActivity.class);

homein.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

homein.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

startActivity(homein);
finish();

}
}); */
```

****XML Code:****

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/Calendar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!--
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/Calendar_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
-->

<Button
android:id="@+id/Date_seletcion_btn"
style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
android:background="@drawable/button_states"
android:text="@string/calendarselection" />

<!--
<DatePicker
android:id="@+id/datepicker"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="gone"
/>
-->

<CalendarView
android:id="@+id/Calendarview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
android:visibility="gone"
android:clickable="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dialog class need betterpickers libary

```
    public class DateDialog {

private static final SimpleDateFormat sSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
private CalendarDatePickerDialog mDialog;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;

public DateDialog(FragmentManager fm, OnDateSetListener listener) {
    mFragmentManager = fm;
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String EEE = sSDF.format(c.getTime());
    if (EEE.contains("Sun")) {
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
    }

    mDialog = CalendarDatePickerDialog.newInstance(listener, c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
}

public void show() {
    mDialog.show(mFragmentManager, "calendarDialog");
}
}
```

// Otherwise create BaseActivity class

```
 public abstract class BaseActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 private final SimpleDateFormat sSDF = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE", Locale.US);
  public void showCalendarDialog(OnDateSetListener listener, FragmentManager fm) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    String EEE = sSDF.format(c.getTime());
    if (EEE.contains("Sun")) {
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -2);
    }

CalendarDatePickerDialog mDialog = CalendarDatePickerDialog.newInstance(listener,    c.get(Calendar.YEAR),c.get(Calendar.MONTH),c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    mDialog.setCancelable(true);
    mDialog.show(fm, FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
}
 }
```

MainActivity.class

```
 MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDateSetListener{
private static final SimpleDateFormat sSDF_dmye = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy     (EEE)", Locale.US);
 //call method when you want to click this action listener
       //call this mothod on  btn click action

       e.g showCalendarDialog(this, getSupportFragmentManager());


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As name setOnDateChangeListener says, this method is called when you change date on your calendar. It does not matter it is today or not. When you open calendarview, as default it shows today's date. So when you click on "today", method won't called. Because there is no change. Choose another date, then try to choose "today". So this method is called on change. [In SO, this question was already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25231041/2255924). Just create custom CalendarView class which you will use later.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion,however is there a way to disable selection of todays date by default ? or do are there any other methods to initiated another activity on-click of today's date ?

Answer (score 0):

`OnGlobalLayoutListener` will do the trick.
So if you try:

```
calendarView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(){
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout()
        {}
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Calendar disabledCal = Calendar.getInstance();
disabledCal.set(Calendar.DATE, disabledCal.get(Calendar.DATE) - 1);
```

Comment: you should improve you answer with some explaination of what your code does. and it could be very appreciate by all future users.

Comment: if you want to disable all past dates before current date so you can use this code