# How can I get currenly selected date of CaledarView?

Tags: android, androidx, calendarview

I am creating application with Calendar View and i want to store data of currently selected date in variable. To do that I used OnDateChangeListener. Everything is working but if I don't select any other date when opening activity and leave Calendar on default date (of course it highlights a date on which I am opening the app), variable is storing nothing and OnDateChangeListener is not working. In short I have to click on any date on calendar to save it in variable. Date which is highlighted by default is not getting stored in variable. Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The simplest way is to initialize your variable with the current date.

Comment: but how can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CalendarView today date item click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19564056/calendarview-today-date-item-click)

Answer (score 0):

I created simple DateFormate and converted it into string. Then created 3 strings like year, month and date and then I assigned those 3 strings as substring of simple DateFormat.